# Loading NSURLRequest in a UIWebView - heap keeps growing

Tags: ios, uiwebview, memory-management, instruments

I've got a simple UIWebView loading an NSURLRequest every time a button is clicked. Using Instruments and analyzing heapshots, I'm noticing that my heap is continuously growing. However, none of the objects seem to be my own,  as they are all < non-object > WebCore glyph stuff. 
I'm seeing an increase of roughly 40kB heap growth each time the UIWebView is allocated/deallocated, even after 10+ heap shots.

Why do these objects still exist in memory, and what can I do about it?

[image: Instruments showing heap growth]

Comment: Can you provide some code on where you load the NSURLRequest?

Comment: It's just a -loadRequest: on an autoreleased NSURLRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to not make the heap stop from growing for each successive `-loadRequest:`. However, I did notice a drastic decrease in live bytes later on, suggesting that the allocated bytes are cleared out eventually.